# Unable to parse Special char Plus Sign (+) in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, special-characters

Is there any way to escape/avoid the special character (Plus sign +) in XML?

I am creating the XML on run time and it may contain special charters

> e.g "Tag+" is the name which I received at run time and based on that
>   I will have to create tags in XML.

```
<Tag+>___</Tag+>
```

Kindly suggest a solution for this. How to handle this kind of scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate a valid XML Name from an arbitrary character string is to replace any character that's not valid in a name by `_XXX_` where `XXX` is the hexadecimal code of the character in question. For a list of characters that are valid in names, see the XML specification. Or you could escape any character other than `[0-9a-zA-z]` if you prefer.

This will have the effect of turning `"Tag+"` into `"Tag_2B_"`.

If there's part of this algorithm that you don't know how to implement, please ask a more specific question.